# Scaling a line/custom shape in KineticJS

Tags: canvas, graphics, geometry, kineticjs

I have created a rather crude shape in KineticJS which is meant to represent a spring. At the moment it is a line with 7 distinct points. Upon certain actions of the user the spring would be gradually compressed.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a simple way to alter the shapes overall height to make it appear as though the spring is being compressed, instead of trying to work out how to alter each individual point's position at each step?

Comment: Couldn't you just scale the Y axis of you shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not my work, but how about this:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-harmonic-oscillator/

It gets a lot trickier if you want to have loops in your spring.